# Delegate permission using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I try write a script which delegate permission on OU in AD, but when I try add both below permission, every time I get on ACL only generic all permission. It looks like they have higher priority than create, delete. What will be cause in this case and how I can fix it?

```
$ace = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", $Groups, "All"
$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid, "GenericAll", "Allow", "Descendents", $Groups
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   The second command, i.e., ‘$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid, "GenericAll", "Allow", "Descendents", $Groups’ takes precedence over the first one because the ‘AD Right’ GenericAll provides permissions to all the objects in that container and the ‘type’ of permission give is Allow which means you have allowed full control access to all the objects present in that active directory container. Also, you have specified the ‘InheritanceType’ as Descendents which means the permissions will apply to all the objects that are nested within the container and those permissions will be applied based on parent container/object inheritance.

•   Thus, to fix this issue, you need to specify only those permissions from the custom permissions to delegate to a particular group for that organizational unit that are required to be delegated and expected to be performed by that group users on that OU. Please find the below example for your reference purposes on how to delegate custom permissions to a group on a particular OU in Active Directory: -

```
    ‘ $OrganizationalUnit = "OU=Servers,OU=SP02,OU=Delivery,$rootDN"
      $ServiceUserName = "account_name"
      Set-Location AD:
      $Group = Get-ADuser -Identity $ServiceUserName
      $GroupSID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] $Group.SID
      $ACL = Get-Acl -Path $OrganizationalUnit
      $Identity = [System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference] $GroupSID
      $Computers = [GUID]"bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2"
      $ResetPassword = [GUID]"00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529"
      $ValidatedDNSHostName = [GUID]"72e39547-7b18-11d1-adef-00c04fd8d5cd"
      $ValidatedSPN = [GUID]"f3a64788-5306-11d1-a9c5-0000f80367c1"
      $AccountRestrictions = [GUID]"4c164200-20c0-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529"
      $RuleCreateAndDeleteComputer = New-Object 
      System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($Identity, 
      "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", $Computers, "All")
      $RuleResetPassword = New-Object 
      System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($Identity, 
      "ExtendedRight", "Allow", $ResetPassword, "Descendents", $Computers)
      $RuleValidatedDNSHostName = New-Object 
      System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($GroupSID, "Self", 
      "Allow", $ValidatedDNSHostName, "Descendents", $Computers)
      $RuleValidatedSPN = New-Object 
      System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($GroupSID, "Self", 
      "Allow", $ValidatedSPN, "Descendents", $Computers)
      $RuleAccountRestrictions = New-Object 
      System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ($Identity, 
      "ReadProperty, WriteProperty", "Allow", $AccountRestrictions, 
      "Descendents", $Computers)
      $ACL.AddAccessRule($RuleCreateAndDeleteComputer)
      $ACL.AddAccessRule($RuleResetPassword)
      $ACL.AddAccessRule($RuleValidatedDNSHostName)
      $ACL.AddAccessRule($RuleValidatedSPN)
      $ACL.AddAccessRule($RuleAccountRestrictions)
      Set-Acl -Path $OrganizationalUnit -AclObject $ACL ‘
```

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/04bb799b-5669-4e7b-aa1f-dcb49e9ab028/powershell-ou-permission-delegation-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't grant specific permission. In first command $ace I define what user can do in his OU. In second comand $ace2 I define what user can do on created object (permission granted in first command). So if I understand correctly there is no possibility to grant permission as I describe in my question?

Comment: No, as per what you are understanding, that is not the case, the first command provides special specific permissions regarding those actions to the user selected but the second command when executed after the first one, delegates generic default all allow permissions to all the objects in that OU. Just as in a folder when assigning permissions, the full control permissions provides.